Почему не ставятся запятые при «и..., и...»?
Бывают такие примеры в литературе или в обычных текстах, когда пишут: «и машина и трактор». А почему может не ставиться запятая в таком случае?

Должны бы ставиться. Нужен полный пример.

обычно примеры так и звучат. «...все гостьи на балу — и старые и молодые — весело, торопливо стягивают с рук браслеты...» (М. Митчелл «Унесенные ветром»)

По идее, нужна запятая, но когда два слова, и есть что-то их объединяющее, то может возникать эффект фразеологии. Тут опять же перевод, и скорее всего переводчик хотел выразиться по-русски литературно, сказав "и стар и млад"(устойчивое выражение) однако, в данном тексте оно звучало бы как просторечие, поэтому получился неологизм от фразеологизма - "и старые и молодые".  Ни рыба ни мясо короче. И, скорее всего, на этом месте тоже был какой-то фразеологизм, но английский. Короче, скорее всего так получилось, не обращайте внимание.

Хотя нет так, и швец, и жнец, и в дуду игрец - нужны запятые, потому что больше одного союза https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_new/3524/и , это меня интернет попутал. А "и [стар и млад]" - не нужна, потому что первая "и" не принадлежит фразеологизму "стар и млад". https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_new/10222/стар

когда слов больше 2, то запятые ставятся, и это верно. но когда именно 2 слова, то тут уже непонятки...

Когда именно 2, тогда нужно смотреть на фразеологию. Выдумывать новую фразеологию, особенно когда ничего особенно в ней нет,  хуже, чем писать по правилам. Но если выражение прямо уместное и "огонь", то почему бы и нет. Конкретно тут, нужно посмотреть, какие слова в оригинале. Но мне их искать лень) если вы найдёте, то можно будет обсудить.


Вот диалог:

— Пришлите машину, трактор.
— Машину или трактор?
— И машину, и трактор.
— А машина-то зачем? Может трактора хватит?
— Ясно же сказал, всё нужно. И машина и трактор!

Есть три конструкции: (1) машина и трактор; (2) и машина, и трактор; (3) и машина и трактор.

И — одиочный союз, простое соединение.
И...И  — повторяющийся союз, запятая ставится, если есть сомнения у собеседника,
И...И — усилительная частица И + союз И, запятой нет, подчеркнутое смысловое единство (и то и другое).
Теория: Розенталь
Пункт 2. При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом и, запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов): Кругом было и светло и зелено (Т.); Он носил и лето и зиму старую жокейскую кепку (Пауст.); Прибрежная полоса, пересечённая мысами, уходила и в ту и в другую сторону (Сем.); Он был и весел и печален в одно и то же время.

Варианты ясно различаются по интонации: перечислительная интонация только при наличии запятой.

Примеры


Подогнали баржу, которая доставила на остров вторую машину и трактор.
Ворота были распахнуты — чуть поодаль обнаружились и трактор, и рассыпанные бревна.
— Машина есть? — И машина, и дача.
Белеет парус одинокий, Валентин Катаев: Чтобы помочь машине и наверстать время, потерянное при затянувшейся погрузке, капитан приказал поставить парус. Никакой праздник, никакие подарки не привели бы Петю в такой восторг, как эта безделица. Впрочем, хороша безделица! Сразу на одном пароходе, в одно и то же время и машина и парус.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
